# Importing hooks separately breaks the component

Tags: reactjs

Importing hooks separately like this:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
```

Is throwing the following error: `Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined`

However, if I do `import * as React from "react";` and then use the hook like `React.useEffect` it works. Is there a reason why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: it should not make any difference, please post your code.

Comment: Which version of react you are using? Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8.

Comment: I'm on version 16.8